# Calculation of difference between versions leads to value error

Tags: python, pandas, versioning

I have a regex as follows to catch semantic versions(in `python` language):

`^(?:v)?(?P<major>\d+)(?:\.(?P<minor>\d+))?(?:\.(?P<patch>\d+))?(?:[\.-]?(?:(?P<release>alpha|beta|rc|dev)[\.-]?(?P<release_num>\d+)?|(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(?P<version_num>[A-Za-z\d]+(?:\.[A-Za-z\d]+)*)))$`

- optional 'v' character at the beginning of the string denoted by`(?:v)?`
- major version number denoted by the `(?P<major>\d+)`
- minor version number denoted by the `(?:\.(?P<minor>\d+))?)`
- patch version number denoted by the `(?:\.(?P<patch>\d+))?`
- release tag denoted by the `(?:[\.-]?...)?`, which can be either an alpha, beta, rc or dev tag.
- The release tag can be preceded by a dot (.) or a hyphen (-), and optionally be followed by a release number(captured as"release_num")
- version string can contain a date denoted by the `(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})`, which is captured as a group named "date"
- other: version number in any other format denoted by the `(?P<version_num>[A-Za-z\d]+(?:\.[A-Za-z\d]+)*)`

This regex works fine and catches versions desired such as `v2beta1.2`, `v5preview2`, `1.2.0-SNAPSHOT` etc, the issue is when calculating the `diff`:

```
pat = r'^(?:v)?(?P<major>\d+)(?:\.(?P<minor>\d+))?(?:\.(?P<patch>\d+))?(?:[\.-]?(?:(?P<release>alpha|beta|rc|dev)[\.-]?(?P<release_num>\d+)?|(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(?P<version_num>[A-Za-z\d]+(?:\.[A-Za-z\d]+)*)))$'

sem = remain['info_version'].str.extract(pat).fillna(0).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
diff = sem.diff().fillna(0).ne(0)
remain['label'] = diff.dot([str(col) + '.' for col in sem.columns.tolist()]).str.rstrip('.-')
```

This gives me a `data type must provide an itemsize error`.

I am essentially trying to sort them into labels, but I have few versions in string format like `alpha, beta,latest, version not set` and other odd stringified types that are causing this error. Is there a way around this, so I can continue with the comparison?

Edit: The answer solves my problem perfectly but now I get an empty output for this use case:

```
api_spec_id    info_version   label
23               v1beta1.3      -
23               v1beta1.4      minor
23               v1beta1.5      minor
23               v1beta1.7      minor
23               v1beta1.8      minor
23               v1beta1.8.9    minor.patch
23               v2beta1        major
```

These are the labels I am expecting, I am unable to figure out the error unfortunately.

Comment: This is a regex question, not a pandas question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to convert your comprehension as `pd.Index`:

```
#      HERE --v
labels = pd.Index([str(col) + '.' for col in sem.columns.tolist()])
remain['label'] = diff.dot(labels).str.rstrip('.-')
print(remain)

# Output
     info_version        label
0       v2beta1.2             
1      v5preview2        major
2  1.2.0-SNAPSHOT  major.minor
```

Other outputs:

```
>>> sem
   major  minor  patch  release  release_num  date  version_num
0      2      0      0        0            0     0          NaN
1      5      0      0        0            0     0          NaN
2      1      2      0        0            0     0          NaN

>>> diff
   major  minor  patch  release  release_num   date  version_num
0  False  False  False    False        False  False        False
1   True  False  False    False        False  False        False
2   True   True  False    False        False  False        False
```

Comment: Thanks Corralien for helping me out again! This solution fixes my error correctly, however now I am getting an empty column in `label` for my use case I specified in my question( for which I modified the `regex` for)

Comment: It's false to said `v1beta1.4` is "minor" because 1.4 is after (apha|beta|...). So what should be the output for "v1.4" followed by "v1.5alpha1.3"?

Comment: Then it should be `minor.patch`?(if we consider v1.5alpha1.3 to translate to something like 1.5a1.3.  Honestly i am not sure how the correct label will be since `v1beta1.4` in this case is not connected by a dot ( so I think it should be considered as a major and subsequent changes as minor), but then the `pre` is also a potential issue.

Comment: Finally did you solve your problem? I'm not so good to help you with regex :-(

Comment: Hey, thanks for checking in! Yes, I was able to modify the regex thankfully, and it works now!

Comment: Glad to read that. For your last question, you should update your question with the expected output for your input data.

Comment: The classification one? Actually I researched a bit and it turns out what I have been trying to achieve is not possible, so I found another workaround for it, I will probably delete the question.